# Why can't I see a build definition from some TFS projects?

Tags: c#, .net, build, tfs

I have created 2 TFS projects , both in the same collection.
let's call than TF1 , and TF2.

Each project holds several solutions.
let's say that TF1 holds : client solution , server solution.
and TF2 holds: agent solution, utils solution.
(those are just simplified examples).

Now I've created some build definitions, for each of the projects.
TF1_Build1 , TF2_Build1 etc...

It seems that when I browse the build from solutions that belong to TF1,
meaning: client solution and server solution-
I see all of the builds, even those that belong to project TF2.
(meaning TF2_Build1).

In TF2 solutions on the other hand (agent, utils)
I can't see any build definitions.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about terminology in your question. Could you rephrase what do you mean by saying "when I browse the build from solutions that belong to project A" please?

Comment: @Elena , I edited my question, hope it will help to clarify.

Comment: Thanks! Just I was wondering what is "browse a build". Do you use TFS web interface, open the list of build definitions for project and see not appropriate builds in that list?

Comment: No , in visual studio, there is a tab called: "Team explorer", in it (at the "home" of it) there are serveral sections, one of them is called: Builds. but now I've looked in the Web access, and still have the same issues there.

Comment: What project name do you see on Builds tab in TeamEplorer (on the top of tab, it looks like "Builds | YourProjectName")? I suppose you always connected to TF1 project (despite you're opening different project's solutions). Let me suggest you to try the next: connect to TF2 project (by pressing "Connect to Team project" button on the top of TeamExplorer and choosing your project), create new build definition and check that this new build def will be available if you're connected to TF2 but not available if you're connecting to TF1.

Comment: @Elena , thanks but this is not the case. otherwise I would see the same build from both projects A and B , but as I said, if I'm under project B solutions I see no builds at all.